# openSuSE 11.4 KDE 4.6.x dead in the water, no response to mouse click or alt+F2

Tags: kde, opensuse, opensuse-11.4

I have a custom built desktop running openSuSE 11.4 with KDE 4.6.x (whichever version comes with the SuSE install disk downloaded from openSuSE.org, I think it's 4.6.2?). I just installed the 64-bit version a few days ago, and it was running just fine, until yesterday afternoon. I had been using a wireless Logitech mouse, and it had run out of battery power, and I stupidly assumed there was a problem with the OS (I had been having other problems before that, which had resulted in my reinstalling several times, with a clean install each time). So, I reinstalled, this time using 32-bit (I need this computer to run National Instruments Labview 2010, which only works natively in 32-bit), and put new batteries in the mouse.

Everything seemed to be working fine, until suddenly once again, I was unable to click to launch anything. I also got no response from alt+F2, so I couldn't open a terminal to figure out what was wrong. I have since tried two other mice, one wired Dell USB mouse, and one Dell mouse with the old-style mouse connector. Still no response. I also have no response from the keyboard commands, though it seems that I can still switch between virtual desktops and add new widgets (that don't do much, for example the KDE application launcher doesn't launch anything, it just sits there and looks pretty).

I will admit, I am totally stymied. Any suggestions at all would be appreciated, though keep in mind that I am unable to launch a terminal or get any useful information from the machine, at least in desktop mode. It does still seem to boot in failsafe mode, though I can only restart it by blue-screening it (the shutdown icon doesn't work, and I have no keyboard control).